# My Custom Variables are not showing up in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have been trying to setup a custom variable for the past few days and it hasn't been working.

My Google tracking code is part of a master page (asp.net concept) so I can't set the custom variable inside the second script block labeled "Async Google Code" because it is shared by many other sections.

Below is my code and the order it appears in my page. Is there any way I can set it outside the "Async Google Code" script?

```
<head>

<!-- Setting Custom Var -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Account', 'UserType', 2]);
     }
</script>

<!-- Async Google Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     var _gaq = _gaq || [];
     _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
     _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

     (function () {
         var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
         ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
         var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
     })();
    </script>

</head>
```

Comment: Calling the `_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Account', 'UserType', 2]);` on document ready might mean that the `ga` snippet has already been loaded at that point, and all the commands present in the `_gaq` *at that time* have been executed with the `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);`. Your `_setCustomVar` potentially never gets executed, because it gets added to the cue too late.

Answer (score 3):

wrap your custom variable stuff in a function to be called and insert a call to that function between the var _gaq... and _trackPageview lines in the bottom piece.

Comment: The important detail here is that the custom variable has to be set AFTER the _gaq is set but BEFORE _trackPageView, since the custom variable does not make its own utm.gif call, but instead rides on _trackPageView calls made after its initiation.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. What would happen if I have a function call between the _gaq and _trackPageView and the function doesn't exist on the page? Would this cause an error? 

I'm a complete js newb, sorry about the basic questions.

Comment: it would give you a function doesn't exist error, but you could wrap it in a try...catch like 

try {
  someFunction();
} catch (err) { 
}

to avoid the js error

Comment: This is really strange... My variables are now showing up and I haven't changed anything. It took 3 or 4 days for them to show up,so my original code must be working. 

I had no idea it took that long

Answer (score 2):

Your "setting custom var" code is missing an end bracket.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the custom variable before track pageview.  You have the custom var in the jQuery document ready shortcut, making it so that it happens after the trackpageview.

Comment: This is the correct answer, really. See [the docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#setup) where it says: *"...the _setCustomVar() method is called just before a _trackEvent() method, so that it gets delivered in the GIF request sent by the _trackEvent() method..."*